# htaccess text file not found redirect to another text file

Tags: .htaccess

I am new to htaccess so this may be very simple to a lot of people.  If a text file is not found is a specific directory. example http://domainname.com/s/any.txt

if any.txt is not found - any other text file not found is the said directory, how do i redirect to a default text file.

ex.

http://domainname.com/s/default.txt

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please take a look at what you're trying to accomplish and rephrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `/s/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /s/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.txt$ default.txt [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Works partially.  I need only to work for text files requested in one specific directory "s", not the whole website.  example.  example http://domainname.com/s/any.txt

Comment: ok check updated code, it should be placed in `/s/.htaccess` file.

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: Clicked the Tick.  If redirecting from one file to another that are different format how would that work?  for example if I want to redirect a.zip to a.exe.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: For that you can use: `RewriteRule \.zip$ default.ext [L,NC,R=301]`